# How to create a vector of array ( string [] ) in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have 2 string, from Sqlite3 , ColName and Value. I want to save each pair of values, i dont know the quantity of ColName/Value , so i use vector.

is there a way so i can create/push a ColName/Value to the vector of an array

code:

```
std::vector<std::string[3]> colNameAndValueList;//this doesnt work
string colName="ID";
string value="122001";
colNameAndValueList.push_back(std::string(colName,value));//im lost here
```

i dont know if i should use hash or struct, can anyone give me an advice?

thanks.

Comment: You can use a `std::pair` as in `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>`.

Comment: many thanks! that will do the work! :D @huu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. You can use `std::pair` and `emplace_back` to construct the `pair` in place when you're inserting values into your array:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> records;

std::string column = "hello";
std::string value = "world";

records.emplace_back(column, value); // Use existing strings
records.emplace_back("new", "value"); // Use c-string literals

for (auto& record : records) {
    std::cout << record.first << ": " << record.second << std::endl;
}

/*
 * Prints:
 * hello: world
 * new: value
 */
```

Here's a [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cb228aed92fa696).

Comment: Many thanks! , auto& would do the same as `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >::iterator it=records.begin(); it!= records.end();it++)` ?

Comment: In practice it's the same because both let you iterate through the vector. In code it isn't, `auto& record` is the actual `std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` object that lives inside the vector.

Comment: You're correct, range based for loops are available starting with C++11.

Comment: i will do it the old fashioned way, im working on a Mobile POS API that only allows C++98 , thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use a `std::vector` of structure:

```
struct Name_Value
{
  std::string name;
  std::string value;
};

typedef std::vector<Name_Value> Name_Value_Container;
```

This is a lot easier to read, understand, and implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vector of objects of type `std::pair`. For example

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> colNameAndValueList;
```

or a vector of objects of type `std::array`. For example

```
std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2>> colNameAndValueList;
```

Ordinary arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. So it is better not to use them in standard containers.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>


int main()
{
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> colNameAndValueList;

    colNameAndValueList.push_back( { "ID", "122001" } );

    for ( const auto &p : colNameAndValueList )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

}
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2>> colNameAndValueList;

    colNameAndValueList.push_back( { "ID", "122001" } );

    for ( const auto &a : colNameAndValueList )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : a ) std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ID 122001
ID 122001
```

Answer (score 0):

To put in an answer, @huu has it right, use an

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> myVector

    std::pair("ID", "122001") mypair;
    myVector.push_back(mypair);
```

Or a user defined struct.

```
// In your .h file
   struct myPair {
        std::string one;
        std::string two;
    };
// in your .c file
        myPair res;
        res.one = "ID";
        res.two = "122001";
        std::vector<myPair> myVector;
        myVector.push_back(res);
```